# Does this sentence omit an "of"?

Tags: sentence-structure

> By Friday morning, markets the world over were in full retreat.

Does it omit an "of" behind the "markets"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word *of* is not needed because *the world over* is an adverbial phrase modifying *were*:

> By Friday morning, markets **the world over** were in full retreat.
>
> By Friday morning, markets were in full retreat **the world over**. (equivalent)

You've probably thinking of something along the following lines:

> By Friday morning, markets **of the world** were in full retreat.

Even in this case, it would be more concise and more natural to write:

> By Friday morning, **world markets** were in full retreat.